# Liquibase - DB2 AS/400 - generateChangeLog throwing Exception "SYSCAT type *FILE not found"

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, liquibase

I am trying to generate a Liquibase change log by running the command generateChangeLog, but I get the following error:

> ```
> Starting Liquibase at Fri, 20 Apr 2018 14:26:14 GMT (version 3.6.1 
> built at 2018-04-11 08:41:04)
> Unexpected error running Liquibase: 
> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
> com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: [SQL0204] 
> REFERENCES in SYSCAT type *FILE not found.
> liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: 
> liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: 
> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
> com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: [SQL0204] 
> REFERENCES in SYSCAT type *FILE not found.
> at  
> liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog
> (CommandLineUtils.java:279)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1043)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:191)
> at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:129)
> ```

My environment is:

> ```
> DB2 UDB for AS/400 version 07.01.0000 V7R1m0
> AS/400 Toolbox for Java JDBC Driver 10.2
> liquibase 3.6.1
> Java 8 
> Maven 3.3.3
> ```

Comment: Just a guess, but it may be a permissions issue. The user/password used when doing JDBC operations on the database will need to have pretty high level permissions. I know nothing about DB2 on AS/400, but we have had similar issues with DB2 on Z/OS.

Comment: You might run liquibase with the --logLevel=DEBUG flag to see if it will tell you what queries it is running, and then try connecting to DB2 using the same user but using the standard DB2 client and running the same query to see if it fails the same way.

Comment: Do you have the `IBM DB2 for iSeries` [extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-db2i) installed?

Answer (score 4):

syscat.references is not available on Db2 for i.  Actually Db2 for i doesn't have a schema named SYSCAT at all.

[qsys2.syscstdep](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcatsyscstdep.htm) seems to be the closest match...

INFORMATION_SCHEMA is the ANSI & ISO standard name for the DB catalog schema.  On Db2 for i, it is an alias for QSYS2.

**Edit**
From the comment by @jmarkmurphy on the OP, it appears there's an [Db2 for i Liquibase extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-db2i). I don't know for sure, but I'd suspect that installing that would redirect the query to the correct Db2 for i schema & table.

Comment: What do I need to do when I get this error?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks see edit about the Db2 for i extension